# Teneray (Elvis) Operator in Thymeleaf on number input

Tags: thymeleaf

I have an object bound in a form called licence.  The licence has a map as a property called additionalProperties and I'm trying to populate an input; so that if there is a value use that and if not then use '1'.  The form starts with:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/admin/createLicence.html}" th:object="${licence}" method="post" class="needs-validate" novalidate>
```

Then later down the input is:

```
<input class="form-group col-1" min="1" id="samplesNumberOfSystems" type="number" th:field="*{additionalProperties['NumberSystems']}" th:value="${#maps.containsKey(licence.additionalProperties, 'NumberSystems') ? additionalProperties['NumberSystems'] : 1}" />
```

To check this i have a span next that does the same thing:

When this is rendered the span works:

```
<span>1</span>
```

However the input does not:

```
<input class="form-group col-1" min="1" id="samplesNumberOfSystems" type="number" value="" name="additionalProperties['NumberSystems']" />
```

How can I make the number input work properly?

Comment: Might be unrelated, but I think th:value="${#maps.containsKey(licence.additionalProperties, 'NumberSystems') ? additionalProperties['NumberSystems'] : 1}" should be th:value="${#maps.containsKey(licence.additionalProperties, 'NumberSystems') ? licence.additionalProperties['NumberSystems'] : 1}"

Comment: Thanks - I tried both with and without the single quotes on the 1.  Both failed but good spot!

Comment: Did you try the old way (ie. not using th:field mechanism). I believe th:field rewrites th:value. Another way might be to use ternary expression in th:field